# Cannot load libphp5.so undefined symbol: unixd_config apache service not start

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, php

When I trying to restart apache service getting below error:

```
root@localhost:/# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
[FAIL] Restarting web server: apache2 failed!
[warn] The apache2 configtest failed. ... (warning).
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error     on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load       /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server:    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

root@localhost:/# ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Nov 17 10:31 /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load -   > ../mods-available/php5.load

root@localhost:~# apache2ctl -M
php5_module (shared) --MISSNG

root@localhost:/# apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 
Server built:   Sep 15 2016 20:44:43

root@localhost:/# php5 -v
PHP 5.6.29-1~dotdeb+7.1 (cli) (built: Dec  9 2016 16:30:46)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Following action taken:

```
root@localhost:/# apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libapache2-mod-php5 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 290 not upgraded.
```

I've followed [Apache2 start error when using php5 module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536128/apache2-start-error-when-using-php5-module-ubuntu-server) but not work my case.

Any one know that, How can troubleshoot and resolve this error?

Comment: Reinstall it : `apt-get --purge --reinstall install libapache2-mod-php5`

Comment: @GAD3R: Not a fix. The problem is not with that module, but another module which fails to provide `unixd_config` (either because the wrong version of that module is installed, or because it's entirely missing). Unfortunately the error message doesn't include the offending module.